# What can be the reason for rough idle after engine oil change on petrol cars?

Tags: honda, rough-idle, gasoline, small-engine, fit

I own a L12B Honda Fit/Jazz. I have never felt roughness at idle during my 6 months of ownership. I had oil change yesterday where they drained and filled Honda Recommended Synthetic Oil.

My ideal expectation was that engine should've been more smooth. But to my surprise, I felt roughness at idle. Whole car body vibrates at idle and it seems very unlikely. Usually, I will not be able to hear the engine at idle, when sitting in car with all windows rolled up, but now I can hear it clearly and vibrates a bit more during cranks.

What would be the problem? Did the Service center guys mess up anything?

Answer (score 2):

Check your oil level ... they may have not put enough oil in (or no oil at all) ... or they may have put way too much oil in. These are about the only two things an oil change in and of itself might cause an issue.

If you were thinking by changing from conventional oil to synthetic oil the engine would run smoother, this is a fallacy. Synthetic will not change how an engine runs. It will provide better protection and if maintenance is kept up to standard, will most likely increase the longevity of the engine over the long haul.

Comment: Thank you Paul. Oil level seem to be fine. Of the two dots on the dipstick, oil level is just a mm above the top point. Oil filter also got changed, will that cause any roughness initially?